# How can i load image url to fit my webview in android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I am developing an android application.Here i am displaying a url image in webview. But the image is not fit to my webview. some one is suggested to use viewport concept. But i am not able to use that perfectly. I attached my issue in drawing form with explanation. I used

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort (true);
```

but not get the good result.
I need to show the fitted image in all resolution devices including 7inch, 10 inch tablets.
So please look at the attached image and suggest me the right way to fit url image in my webview place. I would like to show my image same as in 3rd diagram.

Here is my code for loading image:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webimage);
        WebSettings webSettings = imageView.getSettings(); 
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true) ;
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort (true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
        //some dialog implementation
        }
        webView.loadUrl(myurl);
```

[image]

Comment: Is the url image coming from a html page? Will you have hands on the html code?

Comment: can u put up the code that u have used so far

Comment: Thanks for fast response. i edited my question by adding my code which i am using to load image in webview

Answer (score 2):

you can set **width** attribute of **img** to `100%` and don't set height attribute

```
<body >
<img id="resizeImage" src="you_image.png" width="100%" alt="" />
</body>
```

**Edited :**
Actually i also Having the Same Problem. However Still i am Waiting for the Correct Answer.

you can refere my Question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507281/how-to-show-certain-part-of-webpage-inside-webview-with-fit-screen-to-all-device)

though i have managed some how this Problem with a Trick by `managing height and Width` of Device. and Using `wv.setInitialScale(185);` ByDefault the Zoom will be in Top Left Corner.

i have put my code below.

```
WindowManager mWinMgr;
    public static int displayWidth = 0, displayHeight = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        // this.setProgressBarVisibility(true);
        mWinMgr = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        displayWidth = mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        displayHeight = mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        setContentView(R.layout.view_my_poops);

        try {
            Map_Type = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MAP_TYPE");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        Log.i(TAG, "MAP TYPE" + Map_Type);

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        WebView wv;

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_MyPoops);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // this.setProgressBarVisibility(true);
        if (displayWidth >= 552 && displayHeight >= 976 || displayWidth >= 976
                && displayHeight >= 552) {
            wv.setInitialScale(185);
        } else {
            // wv.setInitialScale(150);
        }
        // wv.setInitialScale(30);


        URL = "YOUR_URL";


        Log.i(TAG, "Loading URL" + URL);

        final Activity activity = ViewMyPoop.this;

        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Log.i(TAG, "Inside OnProgress Changed" + URL);
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                if (progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle("My title");
            }
        });

        wv.loadUrl(URL);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Hope it will Some How Help you.

Comment: Thank for your response.i cann't edit html source.Just i am getting image link api call

Comment: I need to run my application all devices like tablets and note's also

Comment: yes it will run in all devices. you can try it out. but the thing is we will not get image 100% fit in every device. but by implementing it. you can get 90% solution to your problem. i am also waiting for the other Efficient answer.

Comment: this answer actually helped me, this should be accepted as the right answer,

Answer (score 1):

Are u try below code for above problem:-

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width=display.getWidth();

String data="<html><head><title>Example</title><meta name=\"viewport\"\"content=\"width="+width+", initial-scale=0.65 \" /></head>";
data=data+"<body><center><img width=\""+width+"\" src=\""+url+"\" /></center></body></html>";
webView.loadData(data, "text/html", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
webView.setInitialScale(30);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Refer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923610/fit-image-in-webview)

Comment: But i cann't edit html source.Just i am getting image link api call. still not getting

Comment: ok then just use the code for the webview set up. I guess it will help you. Ignore the html part.

Comment: No i tried that also but my image is showing like 1st diagram in my attached diagram

Comment: adding my webview code here:


<WebView android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pinch"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" 
  android:id="@+id/full_image" 
  android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
   ></WebView>